# Testing Firestore Security Rules: Why is firestore-debug.log empty even after debug statements in the security rules

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have my firestore security rules as follows, with debug statements I want to be logged in firestore-debug.log (I realize all rules will not pass, but for now I just want the actual logging to take place):

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function userIsModerator() {
      return request.auth.token.isModerator == true;
    }

    function documentFieldsCheckOut(requiredFields, optionalFields) {
      let allFields = requiredFields.concat(optionalFields);
      return request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(allFields) &&
        request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(requiredFields);
    }

    function editOnlyChangesFields(allowedFields) {
      return debug(debug(request.resource.data.keys()).hasOnly(allowedFields));
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
    match /readonly/{docId} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow write: if (request.auth.uid == userId);
    }
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read: if (resource.data.visibility == "public") ||
        (resource.data.authorId == request.auth.uid);
      allow update: if ((resource.data.authorId == request.auth.uid) ||
        userIsModerator()) && editOnlyChangesFields(["visibility", "content"]);
      allow create: if (request.resource.data.authorId == request.auth.uid) && documentFieldsCheckOut(["authorId", "visibility", "content", "headline"], [ "photo", "tags", "location"]);
    }
    match /rooms/{roomId} {
      function userIsRoomMod() {
        return request.auth.uid in (get(/databases/$(database)/documents/rooms/$(roomId)).data.roomMods);
      }
      //Security rules for rooms go here
      match /posts/{postId} {
        allow update: if (resource.data.authorId == request.auth.uid) ||
          userIsRoomMod();
      }

    }
  }
}
```

My test code, which is running, is as follows (testing done with mocha):

```
const assert = require('assert');
const firebase = require('@firebase/testing');

const MY_PROJECT_ID = "my-project-3we3e";
const myId = "user_abc";
const theirId = "user_xyz";
const myAuth = {uid: myId, email: "abc@gmail.com"};
const modId = "user_mod";
const modAuth = {uid: modId, email: "mod@gmail.com", isModerator: true};

function getFirestore(auth) {
  return firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID, auth: auth}).firestore();
}

function getAdminFirestore() {
  return firebase.initializeAdminApp({projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID}).firestore();
}

beforeEach(async() => {
  await firebase.clearFirestoreData({projectId:MY_PROJECT_ID});
});

describe("Treetop App Functions", () => {

  it("Enforces Security Rule 1", () => {
    assert.equal(2+2,4);
  });

  it("Can read items in read-only section", async() => {
    const db = getFirestore(null);
    const testDoc = db.collection("readonly").doc("testDoc");
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.get());
  });

  it("Cannot write items in read-only section", async() => {
    const db = getFirestore(null);
    const testDoc = db.collection("readonly").doc("testDoc2");
    await firebase.assertFails(testDoc.set({foo: "bar"}));
  });
  
  it("Can write user document with the same ID", async() => {
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.collection("users").doc(myId);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.set({foo: "bar"}));
  });

  it("Cannot write user document with a different ID", async() => {
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.collection("users").doc(theirId);
    await firebase.assertFails(testDoc.set({foo: "bar"}));
  });

  it("Can read posts marked public", async() => {
    const db = getFirestore(null);
    const testQuery = db.collection("posts").where("visibility", "==", "public");
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testQuery.get());
  });

  it("Can query all personal posts", async() => {
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testQuery = db.collection("posts").where("authorId", "==", myId);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testQuery.get());
  });

  it("Can't query all posts", async() => {
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testQuery = db.collection("posts");
    await firebase.assertFails(testQuery.get());
  });

  it("Can read a single public post", async() => {
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const postId = "public_post";
    const setupDoc = admin.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await setupDoc.set({authorId: theirId, visibility: "public"});

    const db = getFirestore(null);
    const testRead = db.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testRead.get());
  });

  it("Cannot read a private post belonging to another user", async() => {
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const postId = "private_post";
    const setupDoc = admin.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await setupDoc.set({authorId: theirId, visibility: "private"});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testRead = db.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await firebase.assertFails(testRead.get());
  });

  it("Can read a private post belonging to that same user", async() => {
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const postId = "private_post";
    const setupDoc = admin.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await setupDoc.set({authorId: myId, visibility: "private"});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testRead = db.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testRead.get());
  });

  it("Allows a user to edit their own post", async() => {
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const postId = "post_123";
    const setupDoc = admin.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await setupDoc.set({content: "before", authorId: myId});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.update({content: "after"}));
  });

  it("Does not allow a user to edit someone else's post", async() => {
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const postId = "post_123";
    const setupDoc = admin.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await setupDoc.set({content: "before", authorId: theirId});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await firebase.assertFails(testDoc.update({content: "after"}));
  });

  it("Allows a moderator to edit someone else's post", async() => {
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const postId = "post_123";
    const setupDoc = admin.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await setupDoc.set({content: "before", authorId: theirId});

    const db = getFirestore(modAuth);
    const testDoc = db.collection("posts").doc(postId);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.update({content: "after mod edit"}));
  });

  it("Allows a user to edit their own room post", async() => {
    const postPath = "/rooms/room_abc/posts/post_123";
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const setupDoc = admin.doc(postPath);
    await setupDoc.set({content: "before", authorId: myId});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.update({content: "after"}));
  });

  it("Does not allow a user to edit someone else's room post", async() => {
    const postPath = "/rooms/room_abc/posts/post_123";
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    const setupDoc = admin.doc(postPath);
    await setupDoc.set({content: "before", authorId: theirId});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertFails(testDoc.update({content: "after"}));
  });

  it("Allows a room mod to edit someone else's room post", async() => {
    const roomPath = "rooms/room_abc";
    const postPath = `${roomPath}/posts/post_123`;
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    await admin.doc(roomPath).set({topic: "Unit Testers", roomMods: [myId, "dummyUser"]});
    await admin.doc(postPath).set({content: "before", authorId: theirId});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.update({content: "after"}));
  });

  it("Allows a user to create a post when they list themselves as the author", async() => {
    const postPath = "/posts/post_123";
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.set({authorId: myId, visibility: "private", content: "lorem ipsum", headline: "Firebase Rules"}));
  });

  it("Does not allow a user to create a post when they list someone else as the author", async() => {
    const postPath = "/posts/post_123";
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertFails(testDoc.set({authorId: theirId, visibility: "private", content: "lorem ipsum", headline: "Firebase Rules"}));
  });

  it("Allows a user to create a post with all required fields", async() => {
    const postPath = "/posts/post_123";
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.set({authorId: myId, visibility: "private", content: "lorem ipsum", headline: "Firebase Rules"}));
  });

  it("Does not allow a user to create a post without all required fields", async() => {
    const postPath = "/posts/post_123";
    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertFails(testDoc.set({authorId: myId, content: "lorem ipsum", headline: "Firebase Rules"}));
  });

  it("Allows a user to edit a post with allowed fields", async() => {
    const postPath = "/posts/post_123";
    const admin = getAdminFirestore();
    await admin.doc(postPath).set({content: "before", authorId: theirId, headline: "before_headline", visibility: "public"});

    const db = getFirestore(myAuth);
    const testDoc = db.doc(postPath);
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.update({visibility: "public", content: "new lorem ipsum"}));
  });

});

after(async() => {
  await firebase.clearFirestoreData({projectId:MY_PROJECT_ID});
});
```

Why is my debug log empty even after running the test code? I have also tried removing the after and beforeEach blocks to see if something logs, but nothing does.

Comment: Forgot to specify that I am running this on a windows 10 machine.

Comment: Note: also posted here https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3411